# Can I Use OpenGL in web and with c#?

Tags: c#, opengl, webgl

I,ve learned OpenGL for a while with c# and windowform,

I want to make a web one , but I cannot use the csgl.dll with Web.

I find webgl with c# and it doesn't support all of the browser.

Is something available can do this?

Or is webGL can write in c#??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing in web applications. You may take a look at [`HTML5 and canvas`](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/). The implementation will of course depend on the browser and operating system.